# How to render the close gadget on a MFC MDI application

Tags: mfc, mdi

I'm updating an MFC Tabbed MDI application to run nicely in 4K.

The close gadget on each window hasn't scaled so I get a big red box with a very small x in it to close the document. It just seems to be this gadget as the Pin gadget and Float / Dock dropdown seem to behave nicely.

[image]

So can anyone point me in the direction of the bit MFC framework that includes this resource?